# Is every rational function a section of an ample sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of Theorem 59.67.10(Tsen's Theorem) in Stacks Project, one is given a projective variety $X$ and a rational function $f\in k(X)$. Then it claims that "**Say the coefficients of $f$ are in $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(H))$ for some ample  $H\subset X$.**"

I found this statement very confusing. Could someone explain it to me a little?

The link of the theorem: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03RD

Comment: I am not going to spell out the details, partly because I don't know what your background is and how many details you actually need, partly because I am too lazy, but the idea is that a rational function has zeroes and poles, and if we denote the subvariety along which it has a pole as $D$, then $f$ will lie in $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(mD))$ for some $m$ depending on the order of the pole.  For example, a homogeneous coordinate $x$ on some projective space gives us a rational function and a section of $\mathcal{O}(1).$

Comment: @IDC Thank you for your answer! But I wonder why such sheaf like $\mathcal{O}_X(mD)$ is ample? I've just learned some basic notions about ampleness.

Comment: There is Exercise II.7.5 in Hartshorne which is stated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621238/422221. Basically, on a projective scheme there is a very ample bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ and tensoring any line bundle $L$ sufficiently many times yields an ample bundle $L(m).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look a bit closer: $f=\sum a_{ij}T_i^{j}$ is not in $k(X)$, but in $k(X)[T_1,\cdots,T_n]$. Then its coefficients $a_i \in k(X)$ are rational functions und after clearing denominators, you can assume they are hyperplane sections contained in some $H$, because $X$ is projective. You can just assume that these coefficients come from $\mathcal{O}(1)|_X$ and powers of it.